# how to do conditions with in jQuery with str.search() or similiar?

Tags: javascript, window.location

i am making a script to filter the listing of posts in wordpress with checkboxes, what it is suppost to do is initially grab the link in the adress bar (window.location) and play with it and make conditions to know what checkboxes to be active or not, and the second part on the submit to send the right link to window.location in order to filter accordingly to the sellection of the user..... i'm stuck in the part where i wanted to check the window.location to define the checked/unchecked, but i'm having a hard time using the `str.search()` or `str.match()` or the othes on the if's:

tryed like this with all the String Object Methods from javascript:

```
var str=window.location;
var res=str.search("example");

if (res!=null) { alert(res) }
```

I want to check if the word "example" is present in the adress bar in order to know if categorie or tag is active, been a few days around this little detail o.O

Comment: `window.location.match` is not a function, because `window.location` is not a string - see the answers that use `location.href` to search whole address or `location.hash` to search only text after `#` character

Comment: the hard part most of the times, is just knowing what you are looking in order to look right =) thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = window.location.href;

var res = str.indexOf('example'); // return position of first match or -1
if(res != -1) {
   alert(res);
}
```

or

```
var res = /example/.test(str); // return true of false
if(res) {
  alert(res);
}
```

If you want to get hash value then you should use

```
var str = window.location.hash;
```

and then apply any described above.

Comment: will also need that awnser =) the hash part seems cool too, even tho the window.location.href.search("example") fits my particular needs in this example, thank you for the awnser (can't vote up because i'm new to stackoverflow, but thumbs up i can give!)

Answer (score 1):

```
var searchString = "example";
if (window.location.href.search(searchString) != -1) alert(searchString);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/cSGre/)

Comment: +10000 for your awnser! lol it tastes wonderfull to have the awnser after a lot of headaches, i'm digging in jQuery for the first time, thank you =)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to investigate location.hash

Comment: for anyone who would not understant "investigate" => `var str=location.hash;`

Comment: You might want to down explain yourself, or you might not. @deathApril Don't do the work for him. ;)